# How to get origin merge branch name with git hook pre-merge-commit

Tags: git, shell, hook

I'm trying to create a specific script using the new git hook pre-merge-commit, but it has no parameters.

Is there any workaround so I can get the name of the branch that is being merged?

Example:
On branch myBranch, i call "git merge testingBranch", i'd like to get that "testingBranch" in my script.

Reason: I need to block merging one specific branch from my project to any other.
So it would be like:

```
if [[ "$originOfMergeBranchName" == "testingBranch" ]]
    then
        echo "You can't merge this branch to any other"
        exit 2
fi
```

I'm having trouble on thinking how I could get that originOfMergeBranchName

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I could run `git merge <hash>` where `<hash>` is either the tip of `testingBranch` or a commit behind the tip of `testingBranch`, and you would not be able to detect this reliably (especially if that commit is also the tip of some other branch). So this is probably the wrong problem to solve in the first place. But, if you want to try to find the arguments to the `git merge` command, consider getting a tree of processes, and examining their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script I found [here](https://thomasvilhena.com/2021/11/prevent-merge-from-specific-branch-git-hook) to ensure an exact match. It uses the [Git environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) **GIT_REFLOG_ACTION** to get the branch that is merged.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $GIT_REFLOG_ACTION == *merge* ]]; then
    if [[ $GIT_REFLOG_ACTION =~ ^.*' 'test(' '.*)?$ ]]; then
        echo
        echo \# STOP THE PRESSES!
        echo \#
        echo \# You are trying to merge from test...
        echo \# Surely you don\'t mean that?
        echo \#
        echo \# Run the following command now to discard your working tree changes:
        echo \#
        echo \# git reset --merge
        echo
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```